# Application crashing in the iPad but working fine in iPad simulator

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ipad

I am writing a game in cocos2d. In the iPad Simulator the application is running good.
While I am running the application in the iPad.

But it was crashing by giving the following message in terminal. I am using 2048x2048 CCSpriteSheets in my code.

I used instruments tool there is sudden increase in memory to 32MB before crashing. It is crashing at CCSpriteFrameCache .
Program loaded.

```
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-6258-64
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
continue
The program is not being run.
The program is not being run.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps loading more textures in memory than the iPad allows? You can only load about 3 or 4 32-bit 2048x2048 PNGs before it runs out of memory.

Comment: I am using 3 * (2048x2048) sprite sheets and 1 (1024 x 1024) sprite sheet in one scene. But , I am removing the sprite sheet before loading the next sheet. Still, I have a problem with that ?

Thank you hyn.